# Expected String instance, bytes found

Tags: python

For a personal project I am trying to "encrypt" a base64 string by appending several @ signs every x characters and then encode it through base64 utf-8 and repeat. I am pretty new to python so some of this code is pulled from others and modified slightly to fit what I need it to do. Which is why I have no idea whether I am even remotely using correct syntax. I'm running py3.10.5 64 bit on VSC.

```
import base64
# Define 'encrypt' function to append @ signs. This could ostensibly be changed to any character that is not part of the base64 character set.
def encrypt(string, length):
    return '@@@@'.join(string[i:i+length] for i in range(0,len(string),length))

# Get user input
encString = input("Enter string to obfuscate:")
print("Enter Integer:")
loops = input()

# Set loops as an int as I was having problems with it being defined as a string, attempted to do the same for encString
x = int(loops)
encString = str(encString)

# Attempt to loop this for the specified number of times
while x != 0:
    x = x - 1
    encString = encrypt(encString,4)
    encString = base64.b64encode (bytes(encString, "utf-8"))

print(encString)
```

EDIT: error

```
PS C:\Users\esmith> & C:/Users/esmith/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe "c:/Users/esmith/PATH/Documents/Learning Python/test.py"
Enter string to obfuscate:bnVtYmVyID0gMSArIDIgKiAzIC8gNApwcmludChudW1iZXIpCgpyZW1haW5kZXIgPSAxMSAlIDMKcHJpbnQocmVtYWluZGVyKQoKIyBUd28gKiogbWFrZSBhIHBvd2VyZWQgcmVsYXRpb24Kc3F1YXJlZCA9IDcgKiogMgpjdWJlZCA9IDIgKiogMwpwcmludChzcXVhcmVkKQpwcmludChjdWJlZCkKCmxvdHNvZmhlbGxvcyA9ICJoZWxsbyAiICogMTAKcHJpbnQobG90c29maGVsbG9zKQoKCmV2ZW5fbnVtYmVycyA9IFsyLDQsNiw4XQpvZGRfbnVtYmVycyA9IFsxLDMsNSw3XQphbGxfbnVtYmVycyA9IG9kZF9udW1iZXJzICsgZXZlbl9udW1iZXJzCnByaW50KGFsbF9udW1iZXJzKQoKCnByaW50KFsxLDIsM10gKiAzKQ==
Enter Integer:
5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\esmith\PATH\Documents\Learning Python\test.py", line 15, in <module>
    encString = encrypt(encString,4)
  File "c:\Users\esmith\PATH\Documents\Learning Python\test.py", line 4, in encrypt
    return '@@@@'.join(string[i:i+length] for i in range(0,len(string),length))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: @JohnGordon Sorry, just edited it

Answer (score 0):

`base64.b64encode` returns a `bytes` object while your `encrypt` function takes a `str`. Depending on what you want to do, it should be fine to just convert it back into a `str` like this:

```
import base64
# Define 'encrypt' function to append @ signs. This could ostensibly be changed to any character that is not part of the base64 character set.
def encrypt(string, length):
    return '@@@@'.join(string[i:i+length] for i in range(0,len(string),length))

# Get user input
encString = input("Enter string to obfuscate:")
print("Enter Integer:")
loops = input()

# Set loops as an int as I was having problems with it being defined as a string, attempted to do the same for encString
x = int(loops)
encString = str(encString)

# Attempt to loop this for the specified number of times
while x != 0:
    x = x - 1
    encString = encrypt(encString,4)
    
    encString = base64.b64encode(bytes(encString, "utf-8")).decode('utf-8')
    #                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    #                               convert it back to a str object

print(encString)
```

Comment: This is incorrect, as converting a bytes object to string using str() will give you this: str(b"abc") == 'b"abc"'. You should use b.decode("utf8") on your bytes object b.

Comment: @ArtieVandelay Good call, thanks! I've amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could check in `encrypt` if the data passed is a `string`, if so convert to `bytes` (unnecessary convertions removed):

```
import base64
# Define 'encrypt' function to append @ signs. This could ostensibly be changed to any character that is not part of the base64 character set.
def encrypt(data, length):
    if isinstance(data, str):
        data = data.encode()
    return b'@@@@'.join([data[i:i+length] for i in range(0,len(data),length)])

# Get user input
encString = input("Enter string to obfuscate:")
print("Enter Integer:")
loops = input()

# Set loops as an int as I was having problems with it being defined as a string, attempted to do the same for encString
x = int(loops)

# Attempt to loop this for the specified number of times
while x != 0:
    x = x - 1
    encString = encrypt(encString,4)
    encString = base64.b64encode(encString)

print(encString)
```

Out:

```
Enter string to obfuscate:foobar
Enter Integer:
2
b'Wm05dkBAQEBZa0JBQEBAQFFFQmhAQEBAY2c9PQ=='
```